# Trouble with inverse of a function

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, statistics

I'm having a bit of trouble computing the inverse of $y = \mathrm{e}^{(2\mu+\sigma^2)}(\mathrm{e}^{(\sigma^2)}-1)$. Here's what I've done so far:
\begin{align*}
y &=  \mathrm{e}^{(2\mu+\sigma^2)}(\mathrm{e}^{(\sigma^2)}-1) \\
\sigma^2 &= \mathrm{e}^{(2\mu+y)}(\mathrm{e}^{(y)}-1) \\
\ln{(\sigma^2)} &= (2\mu+y)+ \ln{(\mathrm{e}^{(y)}-1)} \\
\ln{(\sigma^2)} - 2\mu &= y + \ln{(\mathrm{e}^{(y)}-1)}
\end{align*}

And from there I'm stuck :( can anyone offer help?

Comment: Your right hand side does not appear to depend on $x$, though your left implies you have a function of $x$. That would make it a constant function that does not have an inverse.

Comment: Oops I apologize @ArturoMagidin x isn't in this function, it should've been $f(\sigma^2)$.

Comment: If $y= g(\sigma)$ then finding the inverse of $g$ is to find the function $f$ where $f(\sigma)= y$.  Not the function where $f(\sigma^2) = y$.  If you want to find the function where $f(\sigma^2) = y$ then you must find then inverse of $g(HIGGY) = e^{(2\mu + HIGGY)}(e^{HIGGY} - 1)$ and therefore $g(\sigma^2) = y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swapping $\sigma^2$ and $y$ in the original equation does not make sense. Just keep them where they are and solve for $\sigma^2$. After all, you want to know which value $\sigma^2$ has to attain to get a specific $y.$
\begin{eqnarray}
y & = & e^{(2\mu+\sigma^2)}\big(e^{\sigma^2}-1\big) \\
e^{-2\mu}y & = & e^{\sigma^2}\big(e^{\sigma^2}-1\big) \\
\left(e^{\sigma^2}\right)^2 - e^{\sigma^2} - e^{-2\mu}y & = &  0
\end{eqnarray}
Solving the quadratic equation:
$$
e^{\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+e^{-2\mu}y}
$$
As we are going to use the logarithm, the "minus" makes no sense:
$$
e^{\sigma^2} = \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+e^{-2\mu}y}
$$
or
$$
\sigma^2 = \ln \left( \frac{1}{2} + \sqrt{\frac{1}{4}+e^{-2\mu}y}  \right)
$$